# Testing problems with Entity framework and DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I'm working on a project where I wish to test some classes that are using entity framework. In that process I've created a test DbContext.

```
class FakeContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public IDbSet<UserAcc> UserAcc { set; get; }
    public IDbSet<Movies> Movies { set; get; }

    public new IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class
    {
        return base.Set<T>();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class EFStorageTest
{
    private IStorageConnection _ef;

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddToContextTest()
    {
        _ef = new EFConnectionFactory().GetConnection<FakeContext>();
        _ef.Add(new UserAcc());
        _ef.SaveChanges();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, _ef.Get<UserAcc>().Count());
    }
 }
```

When i tried to add an entity to my context, i assumed that it would stay in memory, but it's being automatically saved somewhere by Visual Studio. Where is the automatically created database located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default EF creates database on SQL server express with name equal to full data context class name. I.e. in your case it will be

```
 server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=Your.Namespace.FakeContext
```

BTW I do not recommend you to use real database in tests, if you are not doing acceptance testing - that is slow, brittle and time-consuming